# How can I add Product Sold Count to My Product Details Template?

Tags: bigcommerce

The Stencil Product Object doesn't expose this attribute so I can't put it in my store. However, the BigCommerce api v2 does. Is there any way to place this in my product template without needing to create a new BigCommerce app just for that one endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not. You'd need to make an API call to get that information and since the information isn't exposed via the stencil utils or a stencil object, then you need to use an authentication method.

You'd need somewhere other than the storefront to make the API request since otherwise you are exposing API credentials where someone can obtain them. You'll also get a CORS error.

Comment: If I want this is it worth creating a kind of "utilities" bigcommerce draft app just for my store? I'm an independent developer for a bigcommerce-powered store and can't publish my apps.

Comment: There's two ways you can go about this. You no longer have to make a draft app, you can actually make API OAuth credentials just for your store or you can go through the developer portal to create a draft app. https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/#obtaining-oauth-tokens

Comment: I'm not sure how to use my store credentials to safely make an AJAX request from my pages.

Comment: I'd recommend checking this https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-ruby-sinatra#showing-the-recently-purchased-products-block-with-jwt
This is the draft app method, but there's not a good way to use ajax request securely for this outside of calling to a secure endpoint which can return the results.

Comment: Okay if that's what you suggest I'll take this as my answer. I'll likely re-use this one draft app for multiple features I am requested to add.